# Remove style dynamically if v-if condition is true

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a simple div with class like:

```
<template>
 <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
 </div>
</template>
```

But I want to remove a `grid-cols-2` if a condition is true, so I try:

```
 <div :style="!results.contactCompany ? 'grid grid-cols-2' : 'grid'">
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should use `:class` if you want to bind a class. `<div v-bind:class="[isActive ? activeClass : '', errorClass]"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot apply `class` using `:style`. instead use `v-bind:class`

```
<div v-bind:class = "!results.contactCompany ? 'grid grid-cols-2':'grid'">
```